# How to fetch text from BeautifulSoup, getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch text from a webpage - https://www.symantec.com/security_response/definitions.jsp?pid=sep14

Exactly where is says -
File-Based Protection (Traditional Antivirus)
Extended Version: 4/18/2019 rev. 2
[image: I only want the text Highlighted in Red]

But I am still facing errors, can I get the part where it says - 4/18/2019 rev. 2

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
page = requests.get("https://www.symantec.com/security_response/definitions.jsp?pid=sep14")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
extended = soup.find_all('div', class_='unit size1of2 feedBody')
print(extended)
```

Comment: _But I am still facing errors_ Show us the errors.

Comment: Added Pic @JohnGordon

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use CSS selectors to do this. This is done with Beautiful Soup 4.7+. Here we target the same `div` and classes that you did above, but we also look for the descendant `li` and it's direct child `> strong`. We then use the custom pseudo-class `:contains()` to ensure that the `strong` element contains the text `Extended Version:`. We use `select_one` API call as it will return the first element that matches, `select` would return all elements that match in a list, but we only need one.

Once we have the `strong` element, we know the next sibling text node has the information we want, so we can just use `next_sibling` to grab that text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.symantec.com/security_response/definitions.jsp?pid=sep14")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
extended = soup.select_one('div.unit.size1of2.feedBody li:contains("Extended Version:") > strong')
print(extended.next_sibling)
```

Output

```
4/18/2019 rev. 7
```

EDIT: As @QHarr mentions in the comments, you can most likely get away with a more simplified `strong:contains("Extended Version:")`. It is important to remember that `:contains()` searches all child text nodes of the given element, even sub text nodes of child elements, so being specific is important. I wouldn't use `:contains("Extended Version:")` as it would find the `div`, the list elements, etc., so by specify (at the very minimum) `strong` should narrow the selection enough to give you exactly what you need.

Comment: wouldn't extended = soup.select_one('strong:contains("Extended Version:")') have sufficed? Or were you trying to keep close to OPs code?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't know what else is in their document. I usually like to show people how they can do what they're already doing in case their is a reason. It also exposes them to how to manage more complex things in the future. In this case, you may be correct, but either works. More specific just ensures you definitely get what you want.

Comment: I'll probably update mentioning your suggestion as well as it is probably easier to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

i changed your code like below, now it's showing that you want

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
page = requests.get("https://www.symantec.com/security_response/definitions.jsp?pid=sep14")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
extended = soup.find('div', class_='unit size1of2 feedBody').find_all('li')

print(extended[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
page = requests.get("https://www.symantec.com/security_response/definitions.jsp?pid=sep14")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
extended = soup.find('div', class_='unit size1of2 feedBody').findAll('li')

print(extended[2].text.strip())
```